# Delete function using href="action.php" method

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, delete-row

im using codeigniter 3 to delete a user, the view file its like this

```
 <a href="action.php?id=<?=$row[TB_PREFIX.'id']?>"  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger popovers deletar" type="button" data-content="Excluir" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" >
 <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
</a>
```

it calls a file using href attribute, and the action.php file is a switch case logic, which calls ''deletar'' case to delete the user , the code that does it's

```
case 'deletar':         
                        
            if(!is_null($id)){
                
                $id = str_replace("#", "", $id );
                $obj_sql->Query("DELETE FROM ".TB_ATUAL." WHERE ".TB_PREFIX."id =                             '".$id."'");
                $return["status"]   = 'success'; // ['ok', 'info', 'erro']
                $return["message"]  = '<b>Registro deletado com sucesso!</b>';                          
            } 

        break;
```

and its returning to a full blank page with null. i dont know how to make it work.

i expect to delete the user and back to the current page with the user deleted from database and the page. thanks to everyone who try to help me with this.
i know its not mvc pattern and im freelancer to this project.

Comment: You probably need to send an ajax request to that page. Does it print/return some sort of string or http code on success/failure? Then use that to determine whether the database delete was successful and if so, remove the user from the page using JavaScript. (Also, if the `$id` in `action.php` is not validated, that `DELETE` query is open to SQL injection - use a prepared statement instead.)

Comment: in the dom returns a GET method with status ok, payload show the id. ill try what you said, but thanks already